# Symfony2 URL translate and structure for multilanguage site

Tags: symfony, url-routing, bundle, multilingual, symfony-routing

How I can make a dynamic url structure according with the user's locale in *Symfony2*?

I explain better...
The problem is not about the language-prefix changes into the URL. It works well.
The problem is into the "static" part of the URL.

For example in EN i would like to have this url

```
http://www.mysite.com/en/about-us
```

in IT this

```
http://www.mysite.com/it/chi-siamo
```

Moreover it should change automatically like the URL prefix also in the twig links

```
<a href="{{ path('StaticsPagesBundle_about') }}"
```

Here, in fact, it adds automatically IT or EN according to the chosen language but, obviously, the static piece "about-us" remains always the same.

Maybe it could be a stupid question but i don't understand how i can put the bundle structure or whether there is some way to manage this thing.

Although about the translation there's no problem, in fact it changes the words into the twig according to the *translations/messages.en.xliff* file, my issue it's just present into the static-link-changes.

Answer (score 2):

For use multilanguage in site, you can set locale to router:

```
about_me:
  pattern: /{_locale}/about-me
  defaults: { .... }
  requirements: { _locale: en|it }
```

And control locale in controller:

```
$this->get('request')->getLocale();
```

Comment: I done it successfully, in fact it works correctly. What i would like to do, is to make dynamic the "about-me" url's piece

Comment: This is not the answer to the questions. The main problem is the statis part of the route, about-us slug. It should be in a language that currently Locale is set to.

Answer (score 2):

For this case, you should look at the [JMSI18nRoutingBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSI18nRoutingBundle). With it you can localize your routes (e.g. the 'about-me' part in you example), not only the sites.